BigQuery wrong row count inside google cloud storage parquets
I'm transfering data from BigQuery project to google cloud storage parquets (GA4 events table).
What I'm doing :
First of all i use source script to count rows which I transfer to parquets
 SELECT * FROM `bq_project.analytics_1111111.events_20240824`
 WHERE event_date = '20240824'
 and event_timestamp >= 1724446800000000 
 and event_timestamp < 1724454654545454)

I get 86554 rows.
Further I export data to GCS parquets :
EXPORT DATA  OPTIONS (
  uri = 'gs://some_correct_path/*events_20240824_1_of_11.parquet',
  format = 'PARQUET' ,
  overwrite  = true)
AS ( SELECT * 
     FROM `bq_project.analytics_1111111.events_20240824`
     WHERE event_date = '20240824'
     and event_timestamp >= 1724446800000000 
     and event_timestamp < 1724454654545454);

I get message after export "Succesfully exported 86554 rows into 3 files"
Next I count row count inside parquets from clickhouse side (target point where I intent to transfer data)
select count(*) 
from s3('https://storage.googleapis.com/some_correct_path/*events_20240824_1_of_11.parquet' ,'access_key','secret_access_key')  

For some mystic reasons I get 172509 rows insdie parquets.
Next i transfer data back from GCS parquets to my custom table in BQ (just to check these rows ) :
LOAD DATA OVERWRITE mydataset.mytable
FROM FILES (
  format = 'PARQUET',
  uris = ['gs://some_correct_path/*events_20240824_1_of_11.parquet']);

When data have transfered and I count rows again using count(*) from  mydataset.mytable I also get 172509 rows.
What can be problem ? Why i get unexpecdetly redundant data inside parquets ? I also checked rows inside my table mydataset.mytable which does not exists in bq_project.analytics_1111111.events_20240824
select CONCAT(CAST(event_timestamp AS STRING),user_pseudo_id,event_name) 
from `bq_project.analytics_1111111.mydataset.mytable 
 where CONCAT(CAST(event_timestamp AS STRING),user_pseudo_id,event_name) not in 
(select CONCAT(CAST(event_timestamp AS STRING),user_pseudo_id,event_name) 
FROM `bq_project.analytics_1111111.events_20240824`
WHERE event_date = '20240824'
and event_timestamp >= 1724446800000000 
and event_timestamp < 1724454654545454)

I get 85662 rows that is in parquets table but not in source table from where these rows were transfered. I also checked couple of such rows inside bq_project.analytics_1111111.events_20240824 without event_timestamp filters and these rows dont exist in source table at all! Please help to solve this mystic issue.
I re-checked multiple times that I use the same bucket and the same parquet files , I also tried to do these operations multiple time , I checked creation date of these parquet files , it is new every time. Pls help

Are you sure you're matching only the files you exported? Maybe there are other files in that path?

Yes I'm sure. I use the same approach to copy data for another BQ project and there is no issues.  I also use overwrite  = true to overwrite parquet file with the same name. I also tried to empty bucket and create new parquet files.
